# Running nUnit Tests in Parallel in TFS Build 2015

Tags: tfs, build, nunit, tfs-2015

We're using Microsoft TFS and the new builds to build our application and run unit and integration tests. We're now at the point where the unit tests can take 15 mins to run, and looking at bringing these times down.

This is my current set up in TFS Build:

[image]

What is the currently recommended way to run nunit tests in parallel as part of a TFS 2015 build?

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question on the MSDN forums too. From there:

> You should be able to use this trick after you've upgraded tot[sic] 2015.1,
>   though it may need adapter support from the NUnit team, not sure where
>   that stands:
>
> https://jessehouwing.net/vstest-enable-parallel-execution/
>
> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
>  <RunSettings>  
>      <RunConfiguration>
>          <!-- Add this line, default is 0, which makes it run single threaded -->
>          <MaxCpuCount>8</MaxCpuCount>   
>     </RunConfiguration> 
> </RunSettings>
> ```

[Original Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/342d4fb7-109a-43d0-abb2-46d4fc9d16e6/running-nunit-tests-in-parallel-during-tfs-2015-vnext-build?forum=tfsbuild)

I haven't been able to verify this yet as we need to first upgrade to TFS2015.1 from 2015.